# Umbraco Media Focal Point

Tags: umbraco7

In the Youtube video at 17minutes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQsvGmnYaUU Jeavon shows how when moving the focal point the image is updated in the Media folder.

I'm currently using Umbraco version 7.7.1 assembly: 1.0.6471.23325 and although I can move the blue dot (focal point), I do not have the 2nd image showing the updated image.

Am I missing something or has this been removed, as I need to keep viewing the image in the browser to see how the image looks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you now have to create actual crops to see previews?

Comment: Hi, Jannik, strange, left it for a few hours and came back and now preview window is showing in grid :(